# django send_email vs EmailBackend

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use the standard send_email (from django.core.mail import send_mail) in Django 1.7.

I have the following call:

```
send_mail('subject', 'body', 'sender@example.com', ['me@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

and my settings.py:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST='mail.example.com'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER='sender'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='password'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL='sender@example.com'
```

This gives me errors in Django:

```
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, '5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure')
```

and in my postfix mailer:

```
Apr  8 12:33:10 ip-172-30-0-149 postfix/smtpd[26859]: warning: unknown[<mxip>]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure
```

BUT, if I do the following:

```
## Email the code
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.mail.backends.smtp import EmailBackend
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

eb = EmailBackend(host='mail.example.com', port=587, username='sender', password='password', use_tls=True, fail_silently=False)
eb.open()
email = EmailMessage('Test', 'message ', 'sender@example.com', ['me@example.com'], [])
eb.send_messages( [email] )
eb.close()
```

It works completely fine.

As far as I can tell the settings in the above are the same as the EMAIL settings in my settings.py file.

Any idea why I would get an error when I try to send with send_mail (my preferred) compared to the EmailBackend??

Answer (score 0):

Try to exclude `EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'`, i run without that option and it works great.
So the final config would be

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_HOST='mail.example.com'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER='sender'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='password'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL='sender@example.com'
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Didn't work, I still have the same issues.  Other ideas?  It feels like something in the send_mail code given that I don't think it is postfix (as the one method does work).

Comment: @brechmos honestly, no clue. But as i think, there could be two problems: default backend is not opening connection, or `send_mail()` messing around. To know for sure try to check if the backend opens the connection by `from django.core import mail` and then `mail.get_connection().open()` if it return `True`, so probably the issue in `send_mail()`.

Comment: I did the `mail.get_connection().open()` and got the same authentication failure.  I'll try looking through the django code a bit.  But.. anyone else with ideas?

Comment: Oh, interesting. I have another django setup with 1.7.1 and the above works (!).  The system I am actually using is 1.7.6 and it doesn't.  I'll take a look at the difference a little more.

Comment: @brechmos it's dummy advice, but anyway, check all the fields. And if the long form of sending email via `eb = EmailBackend(host=settings.EMAIL_HOST, port=settings.EMAIL_PORT, username=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, password=settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD, use_tls=True, fail_silently=False)` would work and `send_email()` would not, then i am out.

Comment: It is not a 1.7.1 vs 1.7.6 issue. I am going to take a look a little more into the send_mail code and report back.   @vishes_shell - thanks for the ideas

Comment: Ok. I think slightly further I turned on debugging in django.core.mail.smtp and everything is exactly the same down to `send: 'AUTH PLAIN`. The hash being sent is different in the two cases.  The first half is the same and the second half is different.  So I guess (?) it is interpreting my password as being different in the two methods. I have visually checked it 35x and they appear to be the same.  Is there quoting that might be going on (or not going on) so that it hashes the passwords differently?

Comment: Argh.  For some reason it is working now and I have no clue what was wrong.  So, no more issues, but can't say why.

Comment: @brechmos niiiiice! Glad that you did what you did and it's working now. Cheers, mate!